# Product of groups with different properties

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, products

This is not a hint-to-solve-exercise question, but just mathematical curiosity involving one my favorites branches of this beautiful science: group theory. Having done some research in databases like [this one](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Ematyd/GroupNames/), I came across with some different ways to construct groups of a given order. Since I don't know about extensions, my knowledge is more limited but I have a question: how many "different" group/subgroup products are there? In the database I wrote, I found things like "central product", "wreath product" (apart from the typical direct or semidirect ones), etc, but, are these products the only constructions? Am I missing other types of products?

Comment: Yeah, it seems you should really read about extensions. This concept covers most if not all products.

Comment: Concerning names there is no reason to know more than "direct, semidirect, central, free" or "wreath" - see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_of_groups). As a construction to build up groups $G$ from other groups $N$ and $Q$, group extensions are the most important class. So the free product $G=A\ast B$, or free product with amalgamation, is new in your list.